# Scope Issues with Filing Array with Integers

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, binary

I am reading a binary file into my program and the very first "thing" in my .dat file is an integer that tells me how many holes are in my file. Basically I am printing a list of animals, and if the user decides to delete an animal from the list, I change its age to -1 and add it to my "holes". The main issue is that I think there is a scope problems in my program, but I am still fairly amateur at C.

```
int * countHoles(FILE *file, struct animal ani, int holesValue) {
    int i = 0;
    int * availableHoles = malloc(sizeof(int) *  100);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        availableHoles[i] = 0;
    }

    while (1) {
        fread(&ani, sizeof(ani), 1, file);
        if (feof(file)) {
            break;
        }
        if (ani.age < 0) {
            availabeHoles[i] = ani.id;
            printf("You found one! &d\n", availableHoles[i]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < holesValues; i++) {
        printf("availableHoles: %d\t", availableHoles);
    }
    return availableHoles;
}
```

So the stuff I am passing in is the .dat file I opened in my main() function, the animal structure I have that contains ID, name, species, age, weight (not that that part really matters), and the holes from the first integer I read from the file. The original file begins with 3 holes, but as the user deletes animals, the hole value will obviously update. Inside the "if(ani.age < 0)" statement, my printf() prints the correct IDs with ages at -1, but when I tried passing the array back to my main() I could only print 0's. At first I though the issue was me returning the array back to my main() function and printing it there to see if it passed correctly. After awhile, I decided to try printing the IDs of the holes right after I traverse through the file, and I noticed that during the "for(i = 0; i < holesValue; i++)" that portion was only printing 0's as well. I am confused because I don't understand how during my if(ani.age < 0) statement isn't "really" punching these values into my availableHoles[] array. I just don't understand how to fix this issue. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: no main function. or sample input, expected output

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your middle loop (`while (1) { ...`), you are using `i` but never setting it to anything. It enters that loop with the value 100 — what it had at the end of the previous loop — and all writes to `availableHoles[i]` are actually to `availableHoles[100]` (which is actually one position beyond the allocated array on the heap).

I'm not exactly clear on how you want to fill `availableHoles`, but you should initialize `i` to `0` before entering the middle loop and increment `i` either once through the loop or once each time you store a new animal id. So either:

```
i = 0;
while (1) {
    ...
    if (ani.age < 0) {
        availabeHoles[i++] = ani.id;
        printf("You found one! &d\n", availableHoles[i]);
    }
}
```

or

```
i = 0;
while (1) {
    ...
    if (ani.age < 0) {
        availabeHoles[i] = ani.id;
        printf("You found one! &d\n", availableHoles[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, see I knew it was probably something petty.. Isn't it always haha. Thank you so much!!! You seriously saved me.. Probably the rest of the evening and all day tomorrow!!